# CalendarView: distinguish scroll from tap

Tags: android, touch, android-calendar

I am trying to build a scheduling application, and I am trying tell my app to distinguish between scrolling up and a tapping a date. When I scroll up to a certain month, the setOnDateChangeListener is fired when I did not intended it to.

So for what I have tried or gathered: I tried implementing onGestureListener (Not sure if this is the right way to go about it) and using the OnSingleTapUp method to identify between scrolling up and selecting a date. I just tried putting the setOnDateChangeListener method into OnSingleTapUp method but I don't would make sense since when I am selecting a date, I am technically trying to call setOnDateChangeListener.

I would really appreciate any kind guidance or referral to another similar post.

Thanks

Cliff B

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{

//Setting variables
CalendarView calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);


 }

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener () {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, TaskSetup.class);
            intent.putExtra("data", dayOfMonth);
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return true;` in your `onSingleTapUp` method.

Thanks.